# parameters on concatenated column Access

Tags: sql, parameters, ms-access-2010

I am new to Access but I did work with SQL before.

I want to use Parameters to filter an query by a date. Unfortunately, there is no exact date but we have to work with text columns "year" and "week". I concatenate these columns so that lexicographic order equals datewise order. 
The select statement works well. Especially I will get expected entries in the DISPO column
However, when I add the parameter line and execute my query, I will be asked not only for values for BeginDate and EndDate but also for DateColumn. At the end the "where"-statement will not work as desired: It will use the entry from typed in for DISPO and not the entries received by the select statement.

```
PARAMETERS BeginDate Text ( 255 ), EndDate Text ( 255 );
SELECT 
    MyDB.art_nr AS ArtNo,
    MyDB.dispo_jahr AS Year, 
    MyDB.dispo_kw AS Week, 
    (MyDB.dispo_jahr & "-" & MyDB.dispo_kw) AS DateColumn
FROM 
    MyDB
WHERE 
    (   DateColumn Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]
    )
ORDER BY MyDate
```

Can you help out and fix my parameter problem?

Greetings,
Peter

Disclaimer: I reduced my query for this forum. the actual query is an inner join of multiple databases.

Example output without the line of parameters:

```
Line1: ArtNo Year Week DateColumn 
Line2: 1 2016 33 2016-33 
Line3 2 2016 34 2016-34 
and so on.
```

I want to filter rather on 2016-33 than applying two filters on column Year and Week. The latter one is more complex especially if you want to have a chart with data from 2016-33 to 2017-15.

Comment: How are you running this query? Unless you bind params at runtime, you will be prompted for them. And what is the value of *DISPO*? Please show sample data.

Comment: @Parfait:"How are you running the data?" I open access; double click on my query. "Unless you bind params at runtime, you will be prompted for them." This is what I aimed to do. I just wonder why I am prompted for parameters that I did not mean to set up, namely for the parameter DISPO that is meant to be a column. "what is the value of DISPO?" -> SELECT ... (MyDB.dispo_jahr & "-" & MyDB.dispo_kw) AS DISPO -> I created a column with the name DISPO. Sample data: See my edit.

Comment: I just renamed DISPO to DateColumn. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an issue: My where-clause seems not to accept ALIAS:

```
WHERE DateColumn Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]
```

will fail, while:

```
WHERE MyDB.dispo_jahr & "-" & MyDB.dispo_kw Between [BeginDate] And [EndDate]
```

will be okay. So my original question reduces to: Is this behavior normal for Access or can I improve my query to enable the option for ALIAS-usage. (I mean what is ALIAS good for if not to simplify queries))

Comment: There is no alias in first `WHERE` clause. Alias are period-qualifying names. Your second `WHERE` does have alias, *MyDB*, which is actually the name of table itself.

Comment: Ahhh! I see your issue. You are trying to use a calculated column, *DateColumn* from `SELECT` in `WHERE` clause. No, you cannot do so. In MS Access SQL dialect, you can do so in another column expression of same `SELECT`. Otherwise turn query into a derived table: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...original query)`.